# Sorting an array in which each item is a comma separated list of values

Tags: arrays, vb.net, sorting

in vb.net I have an array of values as given below

```
arr(0) = "US,20,10,true"
arr(1) = "Ind,22,8,true"
arr(2) = "UK,40,6,true"
arr(3) = "Chi,30,22,true"
arr(4) = "Jpn,50,18,true"
arr(5) = "Isr,18,15,true"
```

What I wanted to achieve now is to sort this array in the ascending order of 3rd value in each element(that is , Sort the entire array based on the values 10,8,6,22,18 and 15). After sorting I should get the array as given below

```
arr(0) ="UK,40,6,true"
arr(1) ="Ind,22,8,true"
arr(2) ="US,20,10,true"
arr(3) ="Isr,18,15,true"
arr(4) ="Jpn,50,18,true"
arr(5) ="Chi,30,22,true"
```

can anyone provide me the code please?

Thanks,
kdr

Comment: `can anyone provide me the code please?` No. StackOverflow is not a site where we 'provide' you the code. Instead, [show us what you've tried](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) so far and where you're stuck. We'll be glad to help then.

Comment: Have a read here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aw9s5t8f.aspx then try some code, then post the code if you're still not getting the results you're expecting.

Answer (score 2):

Input:

```
Dim arr(5) As String
arr(0) = "US,20,10,true"
arr(1) = "Ind,22,8,true"
arr(2) = "UK,40,6,true"
arr(3) = "Chi,30,22,true"
arr(4) = "Jpn,50,18,true"
arr(5) = "Isr,18,15,true"  

arr = arr.Cast(Of String).Select(Function(a) a.Split(","c)).
                          Select(Function(a) New With {Key .State = a(0),
                                                           Key .No1 = a(1),
                                                           Key .No2 = a(2),
                                                           Key .Bool = a(3)}).
                          OrderBy(Function(o) CInt(o.No2)).
                          Select(Function(s) String.Concat(s.State, ",", s.No1, ",", s.No2, ",", s.Bool)).ToArray()

For Each item In arr
   Console.WriteLine(item)
Next
```

Output:

```
UK,40,6,true
Ind,22,8,true
US,20,10,true
Isr,18,15,true
Jpn,50,18,true
Chi,30,22,true
```

- Split input array elements by comma `=> split(0,0) = "US", split(0, 1) = "20", ... split(1,0) = "Ind",split(1,1) = "22", ....`
- Create IEnumerable of anonymous type for each element of split
- Convert to integer and order by anonymous type .No2 (=3rd value in array)
- Transfer ordered IEnumerable of anonymous type back to array

Comment: I did write a non linq version and yours is nearly 5 times faster - Nice.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I was honestly concerned about the performance *with* linq ;)

Comment: Of course,  my code could be pants as well.  I'm a pretty basic programmer :)

Comment: If your code works you could provide it as answer, too. Maybe the PO doesn´t want to use linq...you never know.

Answer (score 0):

Why you dont use a DataTable?

```
Dim Table1 As New DataTable

' Create four typed columns in the DataTable.
Table1.Columns.Add("Country", GetType(String))
Table1.Columns.Add("Num1", GetType(Integer))
Table1.Columns.Add("Num2", GetType(Integer))
Table1.Columns.Add("Bol", GetType(Boolean))

' Add some rows in the DataTable.
Table1.Rows.Add("IT", "123", "456", True)
Table1.Rows.Add("DE", "456", "789", False)
```